# How to install new relic PHP agent for a particular website through cPanel

Tags: php, cpanel, newrelic, whm

My requirement is to install New Relic PHP agent to cPanel Or WHM for a particular website on shared server (multiple hosting). I don't have any knowledge related to server handling.